# Javascript issue because of no weak reference

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, event-handling, weak-references

Let's say I'm creating a chat system in javascript.

```
var ChatController = function() {

    this.receiveMessageInteractor = new ReceiveMessageInteractor(this);

    // ReceiveMessageInteractor delegate

    this.didReceiveMessage = function(message) {
        // ...
    };

};
```

The `ChatController` also does some other stuff related to creating the html for the messages, but that's not important here.

The `ChatController` sets himself as a delegate of the `ReceiveMessageInteractor`, which will call the `didReceiveMessage` when a new message arrives.

```
var ReceiveMessageInteractor = function(delegate) {

    this.observer = NotificationCenter.addObserver('DidReceiveMessageNotification' , function(data) {
        var message = data['message'];
        // format some message data

        delegate.didReceiveMessage(message)
    });

};
```

The ReceiveMessageInteractor just subscribes to a notification (`NotificationCenter` here is similar to the iOS one), does some formatting with the data and passes a `message` object to the delegate;

When the chat view goes of the screen (html gets deleted), my `MenuController` stops holding a pointer to `ChatController`, in which case I'd like it to be deleted, along with `ReceiveMessageInteractor` and `observer`.

The problem is that Javascript has no weak references, so `ReceiveMessageInteractor` is holding a pointer to `ChatController`, and even if `ChatController` wasn't holding a pointer to `ReceiveMessageInteractor`, my `ChatController` would still be alive, because the notification callback is holding a pointer to it (`delegate`).
So even if `ReceiveMessageInteractor` stopped existing, my `ChatController` would still not go away when the `MenuController` stops holding a pointer to it (because I can't have a weak reference inside the notification callback).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The problems are not the references between the `ChatController` and teh `ReceiveMessageInteractor`, but rather the `NotificationCenter` does still hold a reference to both. You should cancel the `.observer` when the controller goes off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I solve this problem?

By understanding JavaScript. The problem is not that "Javascript has no weak references", the problem is that you don't know how to work without them because you come from a language that has them.

How would you remove that reference in any other language that doesn't have weak refs natively? Let's say C++. You would do like everyone does, including the implementors of the compiler/garbage collector/weak refs you're used to: you clean up after yourself.

```
function ChatController() {

    this.receiveMessageInteractor = new ReceiveMessageInteractor(this);

    // ReceiveMessageInteractor delegate

    this.didReceiveMessage = function didReceiveMessage(message) {
        // ...
    };

    this.destroy = function destroy() {
        this.receiveMessageInteractor.destroy();
    };

};

function ReceiveMessageInteractor(delegate) {

    function callback(data) {
        var message = data.message;
        // format some message data

        delegate.didReceiveMessage(message);
    }

    this.observer = NotificationCenter.addObserver('DidReceiveMessageNotification', callback);

    this.destroy = function destroy() {
        // Or however you NotificationCenter works, I don't know
        NotificationCenter.removeObserver('DidReceiveMessageNotification', callback);
    };

};
```

The Observer pattern implies resource management, even though it's not obvious (how is an "observation" relationship a resource??). Acquire and release. No hand-holding.

Also, notice the change in style. And please, learn the language, use prototypes, and, although not everyone will agree with me on this point, do not assign methods in the constructor.

**edit:** I forgot to add: `ReceiveMessageInteractor`? Really? What's wrong with `MessageReceiver` or something in that vein?

Comment: I agree with you in almost everything! 1) I do know how to do the 'clean up', I just don't want to. I want to avoid having that `destroy` method and have to call it from my `MenuController`. 2) The reason I don't use prototypes is because I don't like the syntax (yes, I know it saves memory by not creating those methods for each object... but who cares? the app is not that big anyway and the new Javascript with fix that with a proper class syntax). 3) The naming comes from 'Clean Architecture' by Uncle Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the absence of weak references.  All of your objects continue to have a hard reference, all originating from your `NotificationCenter`.

The `NotificationCenter` has a reference to the data handler, which has closure access to it's parent `ReceiveMessageInteractor` instance, as well as access to the `delegate` variable.  Removing a reference to `delegate` from elsewhere won't break the anonymous function's access to it, therefore it stays.

What you'll need to do is add a `.cleanup()` method to each Controller that is called when it is removed.

In the `ChatController.cleanup()` method, you would want to call a method to remove the observer, something along the lines of `this.receiveMessageInteractor.observer.unsubscribe()`.

The `.unsubscribe()` method should be defined in the NotificationCenter and remove the `function(data) { ... }` method you defined in `.addObserver()` from whatever data structure is holding it (or further down the line).

This is the same kind of pattern Facebook utilized in it's React framework + Flux architecture.  Each component has a `componentWillUnmount()` method that assists in cleaning up data event handlers just like yours.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid that `.cleanup()` method

Comment: The title of my question is probably bad, but the reason I said it was a weak reference problem is because I wanted the `NotificationCenter` to only hold weak references and for it to automatically delete the observer if those references got deleted.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz: Yeah, *that* is not possible with JavaScript. Not sure whether fortunately or not.

Comment: If you have access to a bit more technology, you can include weak references.  You can utilize babel to store all your listeners in a "WeakMap".  Terrible formatting StackOverflow... 
https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#map-set-weak-map-weak-set

Comment: I don't really know if weak reference is what I should use here, I was just looking for any other ideas, besides manually calling `.cleanup()` on my `ChatController` from my `MenuController`

Comment: You could create a `Controller` super type and have your other controllers inherit ( in javascript's prototypal fashion ).  You could implement a `.remove()` method that goes through and performs cleanup on all child controllers automatically.  This is getting a bit off the main issue though.